# Draw MKNumberBadgeView on UIImageView

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I try to use mknumberbadgeview to draw the badge on the uiimage

http://www.claireware.com/blog_files/tag-mknumberbadgeview.html

but there is nothing display.

```
MKNumberBadgeView *badge = [[MKNumberBadgeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,-5,50, 50)];
badge.value= 111;
badge.layer.cornerRadius = 3;
badge.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
badge.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
badge.hidden=true;
badge.tag = 41;
[myImageView addSubview:badge];
```

even I change

```
[myImageView addSubview:badge];
```

to

```
[self.view addSubview:badge];
```

display nothing neither

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 5):

Probably because you set the hidden property to true.